# IPV6 Network tethering on MacOS Sierra

Tags: ipv6, macos-sierra

I've been trying to follow provided guidelines for testing out IPV6 thethering, but i couldn't find the checkbox for NAT64 on MacOS Sierra. This is an image from Apple guidelines:

[image]

And this is the same Sharing settings window on MacOS Sierra:

[image]

Is there any other way to setup NAT64 network without the checkbox?

Comment: 1: this is off-topic here, 2: no, that's a completely different window (sharing vs network adapter)

Comment: Sorry, uploaded the wrong screenshot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In System Preferences, you need to *hold down the Option key* while you click Sharing and then click Internet Sharing, and then release the Option key. You will then see the NAT64 checkbox appear.